# How do you find a parent of a PHP Array?

Tags: php, html, api, http, minecraft

I have been trying to figure out how to get a parent of an array tag in PHP, I have tried searching and can't find anything efficient / useful for my use. I hope people can help me fix this issue.

[image]

I am attempting to get the parent of profile_id, in this case, it's 1. I have found out that it varies between accounts however. I can't find a function for this. [image]

As here I show I can get to profile_id , but I can't get to the 0-4 number above it.
I am trying to find code that can set that number as a variable I can use throughout the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Try a `print_r(hypixelArray);'` to see what the array looks like

Comment: You have to loop through the parent array and find the entry containing that ID. The only way that would be more efficient would be to pre-compute an inverted index that maps the ID to the array index, but just building that index will be slower than doing one or two lookups by looping, and unless you've got hundreds or thousands of profiles in that array the whole point is moot as either method will take a negligible amount of time.